# C++ Function Template: how to call function which returns Template object but doesn't take it as input parameter/

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a template function which takes `std::string` as input parameter and will do some logic and returns template value. I do not know whether its possible or not because while calling this function there is no  information abut the template type and its showing **No matching member function for call to 'functionName'. I am using following code to do this and getting the same. Any suggestions is, there any way to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{

public:
    template <class DefaultType>
    DefaultType GetDefaultValueType(std::string type);
};

template <class DefaultType>
DefaultType Test::GetDefaultValueType(std::string type)
{
    DefaultType temp;
if (type == "Test") {
    temp = type;
    return temp;
}
else if(10 == atoi(type.c_str()))
{
    temp = 1;
    return temp;
}
return temp;
}


int main(void){
    Test intAccount;
    cout << "Current balance: " << intAccount.GetDefaultValueType("Test") << endl; //No matching member function for call to 'GetDefaultValueType'
    cout << "Current balance: " << intAccount.GetDefaultValueType("10") << endl; ////No matching member function for call to 'GetDefaultValueType'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is it a template?

Comment: `intAccount.GetDefaultValueType<int>("Test")`

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg your code works but , method can return any type of value. in example it returns only int but can return string also.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Its just a test code

Comment: @AkhilShrivastav But you must know the correct type it will return at call site. It's not a function, it's a template for creating functions - you must know which function to call. If you don't, you're not looking for a function template, but for something like Boost's [`variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [`any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: @Angew lets say i m having one heterogeneous container of key value pair and passing key path as input. function will find the value for that key and return it, it can be of any type.

Comment: @AkhilShrivastav Then you need runtime polymorphism (such as the Boost classes I linked to), and not compile-time one (templates).

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler is unable to deduce the type of the template you have to provide it.  You can call the function as

```
 intAccount.GetDefaultValueType<type_to_conver_to>("some_value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead return void and pass the template parameter as a reference:

```
template <class DefaultType>
void Test::GetDefaultValueType(std::string type, DefaultType& output)
{
    if (type == "Test")
    {
        output = 1;
    }
    else if (10 == atoi(type.c_str()))
    {
        output = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), "Every template is parametrized by one or more template parameters". Each of those template parameters allows the compiler to, essentially, create a copy of the template function for every parameter combination it finds in the rest of your code. The compiler therefore won't know what

```
intAccount.GetDefaultValueType("Test")
```

will return unless you specify it. In your case, you'd need the following:

```
intAccount.GetDefaultValueType<int>("Test")
```